# Logic for number of person viewed

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic

I want to show the number of viewer for a particular Article. How i will do it in my program?
 Any strategy, someone can suggest ...

Comment: what language, technology etc., are u using?

Comment: Unique users? Page-views? What server-side language?

Comment: if someone views an article, update the table and add 1 to column Views idetified by article_id

Comment: What if someone comes to view it regularly after 1 minute or if somebody refreshes the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using any framework or CMS, then you can integrate either [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/index.html) or [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org) into your website. Then use their inner data to display number of views/unique views per article.

---

1. Make a table with article id/url (or whatever you technique is), IP, user agent.
2. In every relevant page have each page access write down these values.
3. To display number of views simply select count
4. To display number of unique views display count(distinct)

Comment: What things i will consider?
Whether to increase the number of person viewed this question every time the page loads?
then what will happen if somebody refreshes the page again and again?

Comment: this is why using piwik or google is better. they have both options. it depends on what do you want, if it's how many different people viewed it, then unique views is the answer.

Comment: I am not using any CMS and i don't want to integrate any such things.
Any other suggestion which will satisfy both or will lie in between it?